# Connection refused Nginx from outside

Tags: nginx, server, connection, nginx-config

The config

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    server_name auth.com;

    location / {
        return 200 "OK\n";
    }
}
```

```
// to make sure it's not a firewall issue
❯ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
```

```
❯ sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36170/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36170/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1263/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1176/systemd-resolv
```

```
// Try curl on localhost
❯ curl localhost:8080
OK
```

```
❯ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-04-10 18:19:25 UTC; 12h ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 36168 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 36169 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 36543 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 36170 (nginx)
```

When trying to curl from outisde, same response for :80 and :8080

```
curl -v http://my-server-ip:8080
*   Trying my-server-ip:8080...
* connect to my-server-ip port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to my-server-ip port 8080 after 2054 ms: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my-server-ip port 8080 after 2054 ms: Connection refused
```

I am checking the router/networking configuration as there might be the issue. I can ssh into server and the server is a BSC full node meaning it constantly communicates with other peers. Could it be config issue? since it seems too simple for me

Comment: What is the result of `telnet my-server-ip 8080` from outside?